# flutter regex to find two lowercase letters with any number of Uppercase letters, digits and symbols

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am new to regular expressions. I want to write a regex to detect two lowercase letters in a String. The String could contain any number of UpperCase letters, digits and symbols. Just want to make sure that the String contains two lowercase letters for sure using the regex expression.

I tried using

```
RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]{2}')
```

But it returns true even when the String contains 1 lowercase and 1 uppercase. I want to check if the String contains at least 2 lowercase letters.

Could someone help?

Comment: Use `[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z]`

Comment: That works! Thanks. Can I achieve the same result using a variable to provide how many number of lowercase letters should be there in the String?

Comment: Do you mean at least two or only two? The one above checks *at least two*.

Comment: At least two. Not only two. The answer you provided works perfectly. What I want to achieve is the same result, but instead of checking if the String contains only ```two``` lowercase Letters, I want to check if the String contains ```X``` number of lowercase letters. Could You please provide the answer, sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```dart
(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wCvOhe/1). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[^a-z]*` - zero or more chars other than lowercase ASCII letters
  - `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `){2}` - end of the grouping construct, match two repetitions

In Dart, you can use

```dart
int n = 2;
RegExp rex = RegExp("(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){$n}");
print(rex.hasMatch("Food")); // => true
```

Comment: Thank you a million times for the perfect explanation as well.

Comment: At the time, it showed me that I have to wait 1 minute to accept the answer. I forgot to accept it after that. Sorry. I accepted it :)